# wordpress file field not working getting empty value

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i want to add name and image from admin panel. i already created a table in mysql

Name > Varchar[255]
img > [text]

when i click on save button name field works fine :) but **file field alwasy empty** how can i get the file field
value and upload this image to a folder like **"\wp-content\uploads\2014"**

i want to upload file in my cutom folder and save it's path to my mysql table. but not working here is my code.

```
<?php
$id = $_POST["id"];
$name = $_POST["name"];
$photo = $_POST["photo"];

//insert
if(isset($_POST['insert'])){
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->insert(
        'wp_savans', //table
        array(
        'name' => $name,
        'photo' => $photo
        ),
        array('%s', '%s') //data format         
    );
    $message.="Inserted";
}
?>

<div class="wrap">
<?php if (isset($message)): ?><div class="updated"><p><?php echo $message;?></p></div><?php endif;?>
<form method="post" name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">
<table width="464" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="127" bgcolor="#66CCFF"><strong>Name</strong></td>
    <td width="327"><label for="name"></label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#66CCFF"><strong>Photopath</strong></td>
    <td><input name="photo" id="photo" type="file"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type='submit' name="insert" value='Save' class='button'>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually you are not getting the values of the image as `$photo = $_POST["photo"];` because its a file type  you should treat it like this `$photo = $_FILES["photo"]["name"];`.
Here i have made a folder in `wp-content/uploads/contactimage/` where the images are successfully uploaded.
try this  i have made some correction on to your codes might it would helps you.

```
$id = $_POST["id"];
$name = $_POST["name"];
$photo = $_FILES["photo"]["name"];
//insert
if(isset($_POST['insert'])){
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->insert(
        'wp_savans', //table
        array(
        'name' => $name,
        'photo' => $photo
        ),
        array('%s', '%s') //data format         
    );
    $message.="Inserted";

}
$destination= get_home_path().'wp-content/uploads/contactimage/';
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], $destination.$_FILES["photo"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " .get_home_path().'wp-content/uploads/contactimage/'. $_FILES["photo"]["name"];
?>

<div class="wrap">
<?php if (isset($message)): ?><div class="updated"><p><?php echo $message;?></p></div><?php endif;?>
<form method="post" name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">
<table width="464" border="0">
<tr width="327">
<td ></td>
  <tr></tr>
    <td width="127" ><strong>Name</strong></td>
    <td width="327"><label for="name"></label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td ><strong>Photopath</strong></td>
    <td><input name="photo" id="photo" type="file"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type='submit' name="insert" value='Save' class='button'>
</form>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: `$destination= get_home_path().'wp-content/uploads/contactimage/';
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], $destination.$_FILES["photo"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " .get_home_path().'wp-content/uploads/contactimage/'. $_FILES["photo"]["name"];`                            this function is responsible to upload the file to the desired folder.